# How would I select only the number "2007" from the number "20071406" in an input file and store it in a variable?

Tags: c++, file-io

Input File:

```
20071406
```

How would I grab the number "2007" from that input file and store it into a variable and also grab "14" and store it in another variable? I think I would use a for loop but I am not sure.

Also I am trying not to use the <string> library.

So this is what I tried.

```
int num1, num2;

for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
{
    fin >> num1[i];
}
```

But it does not store num1 with the number "2007" and it is really confusing me.

Obviously I have ifstream fin, fin.open("blah.txt") and all that other stuff.

So please help me out on this. Thank you

Comment: Also if you don't have to use std::vector than please don't use it because I don't know how to use it very well..

Comment: So you can't use the standard library but can use streams?

Comment: I can use any other library other than the <string> library.. lol yeah I know its stupid

Comment: @Rup Any other library other than the <string> library. My teacher wanted to see if we could do it without using it, and I am getting confused

Comment: Why not just `fin>>num; num /= 10000;`?

Comment: @XiaogeSu I mean yeah that works but what if I want to store "14" from that same number and put it into num2? It works for only one of them..

Comment: @MattRay `fin>>num; num1 = num / 10000; num2 = (num - num1 * 10000) / 100;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char n1[5];
  char n2[3];

  n1[4] = 0;
  n2[2] = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    std::cin >> n1[i];
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    std::cin >> n2[i];

  std::cout << n1 << " " << n2 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I said I couldn't use the string library :(

Comment: I updated my answer based on your criteria. I left out the 'converting result to int' part for you to figure out.

Comment: That was it! Wow thank you. Now if I wanted to read more about how to do what you just did what would I look up on google? Because the code gets more complicated and I have to select a lot more things, how would I get more help on my code? Thanks though @voodooattack that was the answer

Comment: I don't even think I have to convert it to int because that works out fine

Comment: I'm not sure what to look for, but I'll give you a simple explanation: If you do `cin >> num` you'll be asking the stream to read a full integer, if you `cin >> char_variable` you get more control since you're asking the stream to read a single character. What I did was read individual characters into arrays and output the result.

Comment: Oh okay, because the actual input looks like this http://pastebin.com/XXy1MMfE and "2" is how many entries there are and that long number "200707211245" is actually in YYYYMMDDHHMM format and I have to convert it into this - "08/20/2007 1425". Does that make sense? and the F and C is for farenheight and I have to convert those values to celcius

Comment: Also why did you set n1[4] = 0 and n2[2] = 0 because if i removed those it produces same result

Comment: I set the last character of the array to 0 so that it acts as a null terminator, which allows you to use it as a null-terminated string. If you remove it the result is undefined and may work or crash randomly.

Comment: That's what I thought it was for, okay well if it starts acting up I will add that back, thanks though

Comment: Sorry but I have another question? Why did you do char n1[5]? Where did 5 come from?

Comment: 5 is the number of characters (4) plus the null terminator.